# Hadoop Streaming "comparator.options" not being respected

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, streaming, bigdata

I have a python mapper and reducer, which I'm using w/the Hadoop streaming API.
On the command-line these scripts work fine and perform the expected work.

I have a sample NASA web access log, which you can see here is processed and sorted correctly.

```
tail -n 10 NASA_access_log_Jul95  | ./mapper.py | sort | ./reducer.py | sort -r -k1,1
4   163.205.53.14
1   tornado.umd.edu
```

When attempting the same in the map reduce job, the sort is not being respected.

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar 
-D mapred.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedComparator     
-D mapred.text.key.comparator.options=-rk1,1
-file mapper.py -mapper mapper.py 
-file reducer.py -reducer reducer.py 
-input /user/cloudera/logcount/input 
-output /user/cloudera/logcount/output
```

Specifically the parameter:
     **mapred.text.key.comparator.options=-rk1,1**

The end result of the job is:

```
 hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/logcount/output/part-00000 | more
 16 ***.novo.dk
 32735  /
 161    /"
 1  /%20%20history/apollo/apollo-13/apollo-13.html
 4  /%20history/apollo/apollo-13/apollo-13.html
```

Which has the values sorted, NOT the key as I want. 
I've also tried dropping the 'r' but it has no effect.

In case it isn't clear, I'm trying to sort the results descending by hits/views (the first column).

Any help is appreciated! TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to sort the output of reducer instead of mapper. Please note the sort phase happens between map and reduce, that means mapred.text.key.comparator.options is used to sort the output of mapper. So I guess you have 2 options:

1. Rewrite mapper and reducer to integrate reducer's job into mapper, and do nothing in reducer.
2. Create another mapreduce job after this one for sorting the output by count.